# How to combine ProjectTo with Map using Automapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, type-conversion, automapper, tph

To make it short here are database entities:

```cs
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClientAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ClientAddress : ClientSubEntityBase
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual AddressType AddressType { get; protected set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public enum AddressType
{
    Fact = 1,
    Registered = 2,
}

public class ClientAddressFact : ClientAddress
{
    public override AddressType AddressType { get; protected set; } = AddressType.Fact;
    public string SpecificValue_Fact { get; set; }
}
public class ClientAddressRegistered : ClientAddress
{
    public override AddressType AddressType { get; protected set; } = AddressType.Registered;
    public string SpecificValue_Registered { get; set; }
}
```

These are mapped by EF Core 6 to TPH correctly.
When reading values back we get `ClientAddressFact` and `ClientAddressRegistered` correspondingly to `AddressType` inside `Client.Addresses`.

Now I need to convert these to my DTOs:

```cs
public record Client
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public IEnumerable<ClientAddress> Addresses { get; init; }
}

public abstract record ClientAddress
{
    public ClientAddressType AddressType { get; init; }
    public string Address { get; init; }
}

public enum ClientAddressType
{
    Fact,
    Registered,
}

public record ClientAddressFact : ClientAddress
{
    public string SpecificValue_Fact { get; init; }
}
public record ClientAddressRegistered : ClientAddress
{
    public string SpecificValue_Registered { get; init; }
}
```

Obviously using `ProjectTo` won't work since there is no way to construct a correct `SELECT` statement out of LINQ and create corresponding entity types. So the idea is to first `ProjectTo` address list to something like this:

```cs
public record ClientAddressCommon : ClientAddress
{
    public string SpecificValue_Fact { get; init; }
    public string SpecificValue_Registered { get; init; }
}
```

And then `Map` these to correct entity types so in the end I could get my correct `Client` DTO with correct `ClientAddressFact` and `ClientAddressRegistered` filled inside `Addresses`.

But the question is how do I do that using single `ProjectTo` call and only the profiles? The issue is that projection code is separate from multiple profiles projects which use it.

Here is one of profiles:

```cs
private static Models.ClientAddressType ConvertAddressType(Database.Entities.Enums.AddressType addressType) =>
    addressType switch
    {
        Database.Entities.Enums.AddressType.Fact => Models.ClientAddressType.Fact,
        Database.Entities.Enums.AddressType.Registered => Models.ClientAddressType.Registered,

        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unknown address type", nameof(addressType))
    };

CreateProjection<Database.Entities.Data.Client, Models.Client>()
;

CreateProjection<Database.Entities.Data.ClientAddress, Models.ClientAddress>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.AddressType, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => ConvertAddressType(src.AddressType)))
    .ConstructUsing(src => new Models.ClientAddressCommon())
;
```

Using `var projected = _mapper.ProjectTo<Models.Client>(filtered).Single()` gives me correctly filled `Client` but only with `ClientAddressCommon` addresses. So how do I convert them on a second step using full power of `Map`?

**UPDATE_01:**

According to Lucian Bargaoanu's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71616100/how-to-combine-projectto-with-map-using-automapper#comment126572531_71616100) I've made some adjustments:

```cs
var projected = _mapper.ProjectTo<Models.Client>(filtered).Single();
var mapped = _mapper.Map<Models.Client>(projected);
```

But not sure how to proceed. Here is an updated profile:

```cs
CreateMap<Models.Client, Models.Client>()
    .AfterMap((src, dst) => Console.WriteLine("CLIENT: {0} -> {1}", src, dst)) // <-- this mapping seems to work
;

CreateMap<Models.ClientAddressCommon, Models.ClientAddress>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => new Models.ClientAddressFact()) // simplified for testing
    .AfterMap((src, dst) => Console.WriteLine("ADR: {0} -> {1}", src, dst)) // <-- this is not outputting
;
```

Basically I'm now mapping `Client` to itself just to convert what's left from projection. In this case I need to "aftermap" `ClientAddressCommon` to `ClientAddressFact` or `ClientAddressRegistered` based on `AddressType`. But looks like the mapping isn't used. What am I missing now?

Comment: You simply call `Map` passing the result from `ProjectTo.Single()`. All the profiles are part of the same configuration, the maps are global, so it's doesn't matter in which profile they're defined.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Do you suggest something like `_mapper.Map<Models.Client>(projected)`? Meaning map `Client` to `Client` again? Tried that as an experiment but didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Yes. It does what you configured it to do :) You can always map only the addresses if that seems easier.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the idea was to separate data query from data mapping and put all mapping 'logic' inside profiles. Manually re-mapping after projecting seems to contradict it. There are more subitems than just `ClientAddress`. I was hoping if it's possible using profiles along.

Comment: With AM you have to clearly separate server evaluation from client evaluation.

Comment: Yep. Wanted to separate that using only the profiles but seems it won't work. I've updated the initial post based on your suggestion. Not sure what I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I've came up with.
The `ClientAddress` looks like this now:

```cs
public record ClientAddress
{
    public ClientAddressType AddressType { get; init; } // <-- used to differentiate between address types
    public string Address { get; init; }
    public virtual string SpecificValue_Fact { get; init; } // <-- specific for ClientAddressFact
    public virtual string SpecificValue_Registered { get; init; } // <-- specific for ClientAddressRegistered
}

public record ClientAddressFact : ClientAddress
{
}
public record ClientAddressRegistered : ClientAddress
{
}

public enum ClientAddressType
{
    Fact,
    Registered,
}
```

The profile looks like this:

```cs
CreateProjection<Database.Entities.Data.Client, Models.Client>() // <-- project from DB to DTO for the main entity
;

CreateProjection<Database.Entities.Data.ClientAddress, Models.ClientAddress>() // <-- project from TPH entity type to a type which holds all the common properties for all address types
    .ForMember(dst => dst.AddressType, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => ConvertAddressType(src.AddressType)))
;

CreateMap<Models.Client, Models.Client>() // <-- this is needed so AM knows that we need to map a type to itself
;

CreateMap<Models.ClientAddress, Models.ClientAddress>() // <-- changed destination type to itself, since it is the only one available at that moment after projection
    .ConvertUsing<ClientAddressTypeConverter>()
;

CreateMap<Models.ClientAddress, Models.ClientAddressFact>()
;
CreateMap<Models.ClientAddress, Models.ClientAddressRegistered>()
;
```

An `enum` conversion helper:

```cs
public static Models.ClientAddressType ConvertAddressType(Database.Entities.Enums.AddressType addressType) =>
    addressType switch
    {
        Database.Entities.Enums.AddressType.Fact => Models.ClientAddressType.Fact,
        Database.Entities.Enums.AddressType.Registered => Models.ClientAddressType.Registered,

        _ => throw new ArgumentException("Неизвестный address type", nameof(addressType))
    };
```

And this is how conversion is made in the end:

```cs
private class ClientAddressTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<Models.ClientAddress, Models.ClientAddress>
{
    public Models.ClientAddress Convert(Models.ClientAddress source, Models.ClientAddress destination, ResolutionContext context) =>
        source.AddressType switch
        {
            Models.ClientAddressType.Fact => context.Mapper.Map<Models.ClientAddressFact>(source),
            Models.ClientAddressType.Registered => context.Mapper.Map<Models.ClientAddressRegistered>(source),

            _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unknown address type")
        };
}
```

And yes, after projection I still need to re-map again:

```cs
var projected = _mapper.ProjectTo<Models.Client>(filtered).Single();
var mapped = _mapper.Map<Models.Client>(projected); // map from itself to itself to convert ClientAddress to corresponding sub-types
```

This all seems to work but I'm not entirely sure if it's the correct way of doing stuff.

Comment: The enum conversion for `AddressType` is not needed, it does that by default.

Comment: Actually without it I get an error saying something about `42846` and an inability to cast `address_type` to integer (sorry, the error text is localized). Perhaps that's because `AddressType` is not just `enum` in C# but also in the database itself (I use PostgreSQL with `enum` support).

Comment: [It works](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/a00e68fc364f2f8c4987a9c19a45a6b2d7afe998/src/IntegrationTests/BuiltInTypes/Enums.cs#L103) with SQL Server. But I don't even understand how that function works with `ProjectTo`. Maybe your provider does things differently :)

Comment: Perhaps that's because PostgreSQL treats `enum`'s as a full type instead of just an integer. And if so than conversion is not possible without full type casting I guess. I'm using [Npgsql Entity Framework Core Provider](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/)